# Maneuverable Toilet spray pipes like kink free collapsing Garden hoses?

Tags: water, toilet, hose, gardening, spraying

After my travels and stays across the Globe I have realized that a Toilet Spray followed by Toilet paper is more hygenic than only one of them.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bidet_shower

Are there any toilet sprays or pipes that are flexible and maneuverable like those kink free collapsing Garden hoses?

http://gardeningproductsreview.com/best-garden-hose/
http://clearflowwaterhose.com/garden-hose/

If not, how could one find such pipe/ hose and then DIY them to attach them in a bathroom?

Especially, if the place is rented - what would be easy ways to do this?

Comment: Why not use a [shower hose](https://www.google.com/search?q=shower+hose&tbm=isch)? They have the same internal structure as those kink free collapsing garden hoses except that they have either a plastic or metal cover rather than the fabric that the collapsing garden hoses have.

Comment: @DanD. - I'd like a 'softer' collapsible type of pipe/ hose over a metallic shower hose as it would have similar manuverability issues as thick PVC

Comment: I'm sure you could tee off of the toilet supply, and use adapters to size up to a garden hose fitting.

Comment: @Tester101 - What do you mean by "tee off"? I dont intend to take a garden hose and chop it if avoidable. I just gave that as an example to illustrate a more softer pipe/ hose material.

Comment: By "*tee off*", I mean that you could install a tee after the shutoff valve. One part of the tee could supply the toilet as usual, while the other leg could supply a flexible garden hose.

Answer (score 1):

There are bidet toilets that spray (2 positions) heated water, and blow you dry.  It has a heated seat, too boot.

I've installed the Toto brand version (Washlet) (a seat replacement).  It has water and electrical hookups included.  The spray wand self cleans and self stores.

I can recommend its function and efficacy.

http://www.totousa.com/people-first-innovation/peopleplanetwater/cleaner-future/washlet-how-it-works

Comment: Nice - But looks expensive and a bit out of scope for an apartment. If it was my own place, I'd consider it. Again, a great alternative but not something I can use/ apply now.

Comment: Have you considered a "portable bidet"? They make some attachments that simply thread on to a water bottle.

Comment: @Alex S Since its a self contained seat replacement, I'd think it would be eminently usable in an apartment.